# How to decrypt of the encrypted value in dart?

Tags: encryption, dart, sha256, hmac

I am testing the Cryptographic hashing functions for Dart.  I can't find any information about DECRYPTION?
Can anyone show me how to decryption of the encrypted value?

And this is example;

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart'; 

void main() async { 
  var key = utf8.encode('p@ssw0rd'); 
  var bytes = utf8.encode("Dart and Aqueduct makes my life easier. Thank you."); 


  // TODO: ENCRYPTION 
  var hmacSha256 = new Hmac(sha256, key); // HMAC-SHA256 
  var digest = hmacSha256.convert(bytes); 
 
  print(“————ENCRYPTION—————“); 
  print("HMAC digest as bytes: ${digest.bytes}"); 
  print("HMAC digest as hex string: $digest"); 
  print('\r\n'); 


  // TODO: DECRYPTION 
     ???????????? 
  print(“————DECRYPTION—————“); 
  print(?????????); 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An HMAC is a message authentication code. It is a digest used to verify that a message has not been tampered with, similar to a signature. It is constructed using a *one-way* hash function, in this case SHA256. It is not an encryption, and it cannot be reversed, therefore the value you have *cannot* be decrypted.

The only thing you can do with an HMAC is, given the HMAC and the corresponding plain-text, verifying the origin of the plain-text and that it has not been tampered with.

Looking at the [GitHub page for the Dart crypto library](https://github.com/dart-lang/crypto), it looks like it *only* supports digest algorithms. There are no encryption algorithms listed, so you will need to use a different library if you want to do two-way encryption which can actually be decrypted. The [Cipher](http://izaera.github.io/cipher/) library looks like it could be promising in this regard.

Comment: Thanks Sean, The Cipher is very old and didn't pass the documentation. So, do you know anything newer than Chiper, special from dart itself?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really use Dart myself so I'm not familiar with the libraries that are available, and I can't seem to find any other options on Google.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I will check later

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way IMO is to use [encrypt](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt):

```
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

final key = Key.fromUtf8('put32charactershereeeeeeeeeeeee!'); //32 chars
final iv = IV.fromUtf8('put16characters!'); //16 chars

//encrypt
String encryptMyData(String text) {
  final e = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  final encrypted_data = e.encrypt(text, iv: iv);
  return encrypted_data.base64;
}

//dycrypt
String decryptMyData(String text) {
  final e = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
  final decrypted_data = e.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(text), iv: iv);
  return decrypted_data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PointyCastle (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/pointycastle) has been recommended in the past, but it appears to have not yet been updated for Dart 2. :(

Comment: Well, thanks to Dart community. Leo Cavalcante did the nice job. Its new and improving. Currently this one is perfect to make 2 way secure communication between Flutter Mobile App and Aqueduct web api. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/encrypt

Answer (score 0):

Well actually searching a lot couldn't find anything better than this. The **encrypt 0.2.0** new and has Dart 2 support. https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/encrypt#-installing-tab-

I need to something that makes My Flutter Mobile App and Aqueduct can share secure communication. Leo Cavalcante is a great guy. While we were talking yesterday he comes up quick answer. So this is another love of Dart. Because every people support each other.

It Supports:
    AES (Block Cipher)
    Salsa20 (Stream Cipher)
    RSA (Asymmetric) (working)

Use this package as a library

1. **Depend on it**
   Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

dependencies:
  encrypt: "^0.2.0"

2. Install it
   You can install packages from the command line:
   **with pub:**

$ pub get

**with Flutter:**

$ flutter packages get

Alternatively, your editor might support pub get or flutter packages get. Check the docs for your editor to learn more.

3. **Import it**
   Now in your Dart code, you can use:
     import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart';

Answer (score -1):

If anyone is looking for a rather simpler solution without having to depend on the library, I have written my custom solution on encrypting and decrypting string values in dart, which obliviously can be used in flutter too. The code is rather straightforward, so I am not going to talk about the code on how it works. The strategy used in encryption is x-or encryption-decryption.

```
   var encryptionKey ='your encryption key';

   static String encrypt(String data) {
    var charCount = data.length;
    var encrypted = [];
    var kp = 0;
    var kl = encryptionKey.length - 1;

    for (var i = 0; i < charCount; i++) {
      var other = data[i].codeUnits[0] ^ encryptionKey[kp].codeUnits[0];
      encrypted.insert(i, other);
      kp = (kp < kl) ? (++kp) : (0);
    }
    return dataToString(encrypted);
  }

  static String decrypt(data) {
    return encrypt(data);
  }

  static String dataToString(data) {
    var s = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      s += String.fromCharCode(data[i]);
    }
    return s;
  }
```

Comment: If your application is to be used in anything that requires real security, please don't roll your own encryption algorithm, especially not one as incredibly flawed as this.